# SQL View with table variables

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

Is it possible to create a view and that view to contain table variables for example like this:

```
create view "USERS_VIEW" as 

    tt = select * from "UsersTable" where "UserID" in (128,129);
    select * from :tt
with READ ONLY;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table variables are only available in SQLSCRIPT but not in standard SQL.

So, that doesn’t work with `CREATE VIEW`.

However, it’s possible to create a procedure with a view to access the procedure result set.
To do that use the `WITH RESULT VIEW` (see [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20d467407519101484f190f545d54b24.html)) keyword with the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.